# Abstract class inheritance in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am a bit confused in regards to abstract classes and help would be great.

I have a the following classes

```
 public abstract class AbstractUser{
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

And then I have this class

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractUser{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String company_name
}
```

Now when I launch the application and I check the h2-console, the table Company only has the id and company_name. not the abstract classes variables. Is there a way to make it so it gets all the variables?

thank you in advance

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @MappedSuperclass Jpa annotation on the AbstractUser, Also consider moving the id attribute to the abstract class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractUser{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you will need JPA annotation on your abstract class. This is not specific to Spring Boot, it's JPA thing.

You can apply `@MappedSuperclass` on your abstract class and that should resolve this issue. Find More: [Inherit Super Class Properties](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)